# Regex Expression to Identify Angular/Jquery library with version from source path

Tags: regex

Could anyone assist me with Regex query to identify angular/jquery along with version from below set of samples.

For Example:
From Sample "x_lsmcb_fm.jQuery_3.5.1.jsdbx" and "scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js", I would like to match first sample which contains jQuery and 3.5.1 as it contains both jQuery and version mentioned in the sample.

Samples:

x_lsmcb_fm.jQuery_3.5.1.jsdbx

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

angular_includes_1.4.jsx

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

angular_includes_1.4.jsx

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

x_lsmcb_fm.angular_1.8.0_min.jsdbx

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

angular_includes_1.4.jsx

x_73376_geofluent.Angular_1_4_framework.jsdbx

scripts/lib/jquery_includes.js

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Similar to SQL, regular expressions exists in many programming languages and so also exitst lots of dialects.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following regex:

```
.*j[qQ]uery_[\d\.]+.*
```

Explanation:

- `.*`: any combination of characters
- `j[qQ]uery`: "j" + either lower or upper "q" + "uery"
- `_`: underscore
- `[\d\.]+`: any combination of numbers and dots
- `.*`: any combination of characters

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/5r76Xt/1).

Answer (score 0):

/((?=.*angular|jquery|jQuery|Angular|angularjs|AngularJS|JQUERY)(?=.*\d+.\d+)|(?=.*angular|jquery|jQuery|Angular|angularjs|AngularJS|JQUERY)(?=.*\d+_\d+)).*$/gm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).